# Convert affine coordinates to projective coordinates?

Tags: elliptic-curves, projective-geometry, affine-geometry

> For any rational map represented by $(\frac{x^4+3y}{x^2+1},
>  \frac{x+1}{y})$ in affine coordinates, write down the corresponding
>   representation $[F_1(X, Y, Z) : F_2(X, Y, Z) : F_3(X, Y, Z)]$ in
>   projective coordinates.

My understanding is that a point in affine coordinates $(X', Y')$ has a projective representation of $(X', Y', 1)$. So is the answer just $(\frac{x^4+3y}{x^2+1},
 \frac{x+1}{y}, 1)$? That doesn't seem right to me. How should I properly convert these points?

Comment: Hmm, what does $(\frac{x^2+3y}{x^2},\frac{x+1}{y})$ actually mean here? Is it a two-variable parameterization of a subset or $\mathbb R^2$ or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by $y(x^2+1)$ so your map is $((x^4+3y)y, (x+1)(x^2+1), y(x^2+1))$.
Now further you want $X,Y,Z$ to be homogeneous so set $x=\frac{X}{Z}$ and $y=\frac{Y}{Z}$ and now multiply by the lowest power of $Z$ to clear the denominators.

Comment: You mean the higher power of $Z$ in order to clean the denomnators right?